# SignalR disconnecting all Clients when a single client refresh the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have problem with signalR with multiple client and async background task.

Here is my Scenario:
I have multiple clients doing multiple downloads.. they can download files simultaneously, I use signalR to send them the progress of there download. I handled it fine but the problem is when a single user invokes the Disconnect Method or he leaves or refresh its page, signalR will Disconnect all its client not only the one who is disconnecting which will interrupt the progress report for other client. How will I resolve this issue.?? Is there Any other way handling it??

additional:

```
 private async Task WriteRecords([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dataRequest,int countno, VMEXPORT[] arrVmExport, bool createHeaderyn, string filePath )
    {

        string fileName = filePath.Replace(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + "Csv\\", "").Replace(".csv", "");
        int datapage = (countno / 192322)+1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= datapage; )
        {
            dataRequest.Page = i;
            dataRequest.PageSize = 192322;
            var write = _serviceAgent.FetchByRole("", "", CurrentUser.Linkcd, CurrentUser.Rolecd).ToDataSourceResult(dataRequest);
            await  Task.Run(()=>write.Data.Cast<AGENT>().WriteToCSV(new AGENT(), createHeaderyn, arrVmExport, filePath));
            createHeaderyn = false;   
            i = i + 1;    
            double percentage = (i * 100) / datapage;
            SendProgress(percentage, countno,fileName);
        }
    }
```

Here is the set up in my BaseController which calls the hub context:

```
    public void SendNotification(string fileNametx, bool createdyn)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SignalRHubHelper>();
        context.Clients.User(CurrentUser.Usernm + '-' + CurrentUser.GUID)
                .receiveNotification("Export", CurrentUser.Usernm, "info", fileNametx, createdyn);
    }

    public void SendProgress(double recordCount, int totalCount,string fileName)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SignalRHubHelper>();
        context.Clients.User(CurrentUser.Usernm + '-' + CurrentUser.GUID).reportProgress(recordCount, totalCount,fileName);
    }
```

And Here is my controller Method:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> _Export([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dataRequest, string columns,int countno, string menunm)
    {
        var fileNametx = AgentsPrompttx + DateTime.Now.ToString(GeneralConst.L_STRING_DATE4) + ".csv";
        SendNotification(fileNametx, false);
        var filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + "Csv\\";
        var vmexport = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<VMEXPORT[]>(columns);
        dataRequest.GroupingToSorting();
        dataRequest.PageSize = 0; // set to zero
        await WriteRecords(dataRequest,countno, vmexport, true, filePath + fileNametx);
        SendNotification(fileNametx, true);
        return File(filePath + fileNametx, WebConst.L_CONTENTTYPE_APP_OCTET, fileNametx);

    }
```

JavaSciprt:

```
        init: function (element) {
        var self = this;
        self.msgno = undefined;

        self.sfiHubConnection = $.connection.signalRHubHelper;
        self.initSignalRClients();
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.start({ transport: "longPolling" }).done(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                self.sfiHubConnection.server.getAllStatus();
                self.sfiHubConnection.server.brodcastLogIn($('#usernm').text());
            }, 1000);
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("signal Failed")
        });
    },

    triggerReconnect: function () {
        var self = this;
        $.connection.hub.stateChanged(function (change) {
            if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.disconnected) {
                $.connection.hub.stop();
               self.init();
            }
        });
    },

    deleteFile: function (controllertx, filenametx) {
        $('#close_dl_link').on('click', function () {
            $.get(GetAppPath() + controllertx + '/_DeleteFile/?Filenametx='+filenametx, function () {
                return true;
            });
        });

    },

    initSignalRClients: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.sfiHubConnection = $.connection.signalRHubHelper

        self.sfiHubConnection.client.setOnline = function (usernm) {
            if ($('#user_kgrid').data('kendoGrid') != undefined)
                $('#user_kgrid').data('kendoGrid').tbody.find('td:contains("' + usernm + '")').eq(0).parent('tr').find('td:contains("Offline")').html('<span><i class="icon-ok-sign"></i></span> Online')
        };

        self.sfiHubConnection.client.receiveNotification = function (controller, totx, type, fileNametx, createdyn) {      
            if (totx == $('#usernm').text()) {
                if (!createdyn) {
                    self.init();
                    var fileId=fileNametx.replace(".csv","")
                    var icon = "icon-download";
                    var title = fileId +':'+ ' <span id="' + fileId + '"></span> <br>';
                    var message = "Creating file kindly wait..";
                    var delay = 0;
                    SfiNotify(icon, title, message, 'info', "", "", "", "", delay);
                }
                else if (createdyn && fileNametx !== "") {
                    console.log("download available: "+fileNametx)
                    var elementid = fileNametx.replace(".csv", "");
                    $('#' + elementid).parents(".alert").each(function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                    var icon = "icon-download";
                    var title = " File ready for download !<br>" + "<strong>" + fileNametx + "</strong><br>";
                    var message = "Click here to download the file!";
                    var url = GetAppPath() + controller + '/_Download/?filenametx=' + fileNametx;
                    var delay = 0;
                    SfiNotify(icon, title, message, 'info', url, "", "", "", delay);
                    if ($('#close_dl_link').length > 0) {
                        self.deleteFile(controller, fileNametx);
                    }
                }

            }
            else
                return false;
        };

        self.sfiHubConnection.client.reportProgress = function (recordCount, totalRecord, fileName) {          
            var progress = recordCount + "% of " + totalRecord;
            console.log("PROGRESS FOR: " + fileName + "TOTAL: "+recordCount);
            if ($('#' + fileName).length > 0) {
                if (recordCount > 100)
                    return false;
                $('#' + fileName).text(progress);
            }
            else if($('#' + fileName).length == 0)
            {
                if (recordCount > 100)
                    return false;
                var icon = "icon-download";
                var title = ' Processing Records <span id=' + fileName + '>' + progress + '</span> <br>';
                var message = "Creating file kindly wait..";
                var delay = 0;
                SfiNotify(icon, title, message, 'info', "", "", "", "", delay);
            }


        };
```

Comment: Signalr is responsible for itself , but it is possible to show your code to clearly understandable.

Comment: wait i will update actually i have posted it in another question

Comment: What approach you have implemented in OnDisconnected event.

Comment: @sehtaumesh ITs just retur base.OnDisconnected(); i should restart it as based on my javascript

Comment: It's probably because SendProgress fails when a user disconnects. The server crashes and everything restarts.

Comment: @Aron that is what i observe which unlikely a bug on signalr one client disconnects, crash all the connected ones

Comment: It should be an async task which is main objective of signalR. but we cannot disconnect just single instance which is only the bearer of that connection id that calls disconnects

Comment: No. The bug is in YOUR code. YOU are trying to send to a client that has disconnected.

Comment: No i guess not. the question i have in mind is how would i only call the disconnect for only my user id not all that is connected. why does it needs to affect all. It is also working fine in local IIS but on Server it fails

Comment: The point isn't you calling Disconnect on your client...its that AFTER he disconnects, there is still code trying to signal him BY ID.

Comment: why does even the connected clients disconnects?? im telling the direct point that all other clients disconnects..